# What formats of bootable USB does 2018 Mac mini support?

Tags: mac

What formats of bootable USB does 2018 Mac mini (with T2 chip) support? Is it different from the older models of Mac minis?

I know the foloowing:
 - T2 MacMini can not boot from Fat32 USB with installed Groob (old one can from the same stick)
 - T2 MacMini can boot from USB stick created by Etcher from Ubuntu iso installer image (and I don't understand, what format Etcher creates)

Comment: By format do you mean filesystem on USB key? What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I'm about how to do it bootable for Mac?